# Javascript - Ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax

```
function ajax(options) {
 options = {
  type: options.type || "POST",
  url: options.url || "",
  timeout: options.timeout || 5000,
  onComplete: options.onComplete || function(){},
  onError: options.onError || function(){},
  onSuccess: options.onSuccess || function(){},
  data: options.data || ""
 };
 if (typeof XMLHttpRequest == "undefined") {
  XMLHttpRequest = function(){
   try { return new XMLHttpRequest(); } catch(e) {}
   try { return new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP.6.0"); } catch (e) {}
   try { return new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP.3.0"); } catch (e) {}
   try { return new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP"); } catch (e) {}
   try { return new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP"); } catch (e) {}
   return null;
  };
 }
 var xml = new XMLHttpRequest();
 xml.open(options.type, options.url, true);
 var timeoutLength = options.timeout;
 var requestDone = false;
 setTimeout(function(){
  requestDone = true;
 }, timeoutLength);
 xml.onreadystatechange = function(){
  if (xml.readyState == 4 && !requestDone) {
   if (httpSuccess(xml)) {
    options.onSuccess(httpData(xml, options.type));
   } else {
    options.onError();
   }
   options.onComplete();
   xml = null;
  }
 };
 xml.send();
 function httpSuccess(r) {
  try {
   return (r.status >= 200 && r.status < 300) || r.status == 304 || navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Safari") >= 0 && typeof r.status == "undefined";
  } catch(e) {
   return false;
  }
 }
 function httpData(r.type) {
  var ct = r.getResponseHeader("content-type");
  var data = !type && ct && ct.indexOf("xml") >= 0;
  data = type == "xml" || data ? r.responseXML : r.responseText;
  if (type == "script") eval.call(window, data);
  return data;
 }
}
function serialize(a) {
 var s = [];
 if (a.constructor == Array) {
  for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) s.push(a[i].name + "=" + encodeURIComponent(a[i].value));
 } else {
  for (var j in a) s.push(j + "=" + encodeURIComponent(a[j]));
 }
 return s.join("&");
}
```

This code does not work. What is the problem?

Comment: describe "does not work" a little more detailed, please. do you get any error messages? doesn't this work in all browsers or just in one? what browsers have you tested? what have you tried yourself to find the problem?

Comment: I might have mistyped something. What soft can I use to find the mistake?

Comment: for firefox, there's a great addon called "firebug" you could use

Comment: Please update your title and your question to be more specific.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`function httpData(r.type) {` to `function httpData(r,type) {`

Answer (score 3):

I don't think you will ever have the right answer to this question since almost all developers are using Javascript libraries to handle that!

Why don't you do the same here, that would be a lost faster?

Checkout out JQuery if you don't know it already: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: perhaps faster to write. But you get a more data to download to the client. So in some cases, pure JavaScript to be better